# detect specific ajax request (data sent) from multiple request

Tags: jquery

i am sending multiple jquery ajax request from a single function one after one
some from which respond and some might not
is there any possible way to get the $_POST[parameters] send in specific request at request result
i tried some code but end up with over writing issue

```
$.ajax({
            url:  "ajax_files/bulk_dispatch_ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { action:value,
                    trackingCode:specific_value

            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                // counting requests
                countingRequests = countingRequests+1;

            },
            success:function(response)
            {


            },
            timeout: 10000,
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus, tex) {

                console.log(xhr);
                // i want (specific_value) here in multiple request , this function is called multiple times, so prevent the
```

chance of overwriting

```
                if(xhr.status != '200')
                {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Please post your code for more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as i know, there is no direct way to access the sent data. But you can hand it over to your callback function by your own, e.g. wrapping the callback into a own function, example:

```
function yourCustomAjaxFunction(data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: getUrlFromSomewhere(),
        data: data,
        method: 'POST',
        success: createCallback(data, callback)
    });
}

function createCallback(sentData, callback) {
    return function(receivedData, textStatus, jqXhr) {
        if (typeof(callback) === 'function') {
            callback(sentData, receivedData, textStatus, jqXhr);
        }
    }
}
```

In the example the function "yourCustomAjaxFunction" is the function mentioned ("i am sending multiple jquery ajax request from a single function").
Now you can use this as follows:

```
//example function which receives the sent data as well
function exampleLoggingCallback(sentData, receivedData, textStatus, jqXhr) {
    console.log('Sent data: ' + sentData);
    console.log('Received data: ' + receivedData);
}

//example call to your ajax function:
yourCustomAjaxFunction({foo: 'bar'}, exampleLoggingCallback);
```

Hope this helps.

p.S. posted examples are untested.

Comment: that is s/t i want to from a long time

Comment: glad to hear - can you accept the answer in this case? :)